# Why is PHP treating my where clause differently than phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query that works perfectly in workbench, but returns all rows in php.  It is almost as if php is completly ignoring the where clause.

```
 $sql = "SELECT
    f.name facility_name,
    CONCAT(f.code, '', LPAD(a.id, 6, '0')) DBNUM,
    s.account_number account_number,
    a.patient_last_name last_name,
    a.patient_first_name first_name,
    s.admission_date admit_date,
    s.discharge_date,
    s.total_charge,
    acttype.name claim_type,
    cstat.name claim_status,
    date(s.created) as created,
    s.close_date,
    s.close_notes,
    u.name
FROM
    services s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    accounts a ON s.account_id = a.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    account_types acttype ON acttype.id = a.account_type_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    claim_statuses cstat ON cstat.id = s.claim_status_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    facilities f ON f.id = a.facility_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    users      u ON u.id = s.modified_by
where 
  s.created = '2018-09-24'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) fputcsv($report_csv, $row);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: It'd help if you showed *how* you were executing this in PHP.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited it to show how I am executing it in php.

Comment: Are you sure you want left outer join and not say inner join?

Comment: Inner joins didnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

The LEFT OUTER JOIN will give you all the data from your tables. In your case seems that Inner Join will work out. In your database, there is records that were created in a date different of 2018-09-24?

If all your data has the created column with value 2018-09-24, the statement will actually return all the data.

If not, try change your JOINS to LEFT or INNER. That depends on how your tables are related

Comment: Thanks.  Inner Joins return no results, and the left join returns the same thing as the left outer join.  The values in the created column are different going back 5 years.  This is a php script to generate a report, but I just cannot figure out why it returns all data.  I was thinking it had something to due with the Date format.  The created field is Date and not Datetime.

Comment: try to change your where to:
`where s.created = '20180924'`.

If doenst work try this:
`where DAY(s.created) = 24 AND MONTH(s.created) = 09 AND YEAR(s.created) = 2018`

Comment: Same result.  This is crazy.  It doesn't seem to matter what I put in the where clause.

Comment: To see if the problem is the where clause, try to put a different condition, like:
`WHERE s.id = 1`. Something that you will know that will return you a specific row. Just to know if the problem is the where with a date condition

Comment: It doesn't matter what I put in the where clause. I am thinking I need to add it to the s table join statement directly. Not sure though

Comment: okay. As i sad before, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will give you all the data. 
The condition of your date is really wrong. Try to change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` and put the where clause like i sad before: `where s.created = '20180924'` or `where DAY(s.created) = 24 AND MONTH(s.created) = 09 AND YEAR(s.created) = 2018`. It doenst make sense to use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your case

Comment: I understand the joins better now, but I still get the same result on the date.  What confuses me is why the query works perfectly in phpmyadmin and mysqlworkbench.   I have changed to LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN, I have tried those variations on the where clause, and I have added the criteria to the ON statement to try and narrow the scope of the JOIN.  No luck.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was the version of PHP.  I was running these queries using PHP5 and after upgrading to PHP7.2 everything works as it should.